How to integrate function involving gradient of multivariate function?
Let's say we have a function f(x,y) = $x^2 + y^2$ , where x and y are real numbers and I have to compute the integral
$ I = \int g(v) \triangledown_{v} f(v) dv $, where v = [x, y]$^T$ and g(v) is a $R^2 \rightarrow R$ is another function.
If possible can you point to relevant resources where I can learn about the problem stated above.

Just compute the gradient and replace with its expression in I.

Is that a gradient or a directional derivative?

@KurtG. It's gradient

Can you calculate it for us?

@KurtG. In this case it will be 2$[x, y]^T$

Right. To turn this into a meaningful exercise you may want to choose an explicit example for $g$ now and a region over which you integrate. Then proceed. No resource is needed to learn that.

@KurtG. So do we have to integrate component-wise and for each component integrate it by parts?

We integrate component-wise over a region in $\mathbb R^2,.$ How exactly we do that depends on $g$ and on the region.
